# How to get rid of the streaks after layout animation in framer.motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

When framer.motion animates between two layout-states (using AnimateSharedLayout) the animation leave streaks outside of the animated element. It's hard to explain but i created a very minimal example in codesandbox. It happens when the box gets smaller.

Am I doing something wrong or do anyone know a workaround?

Best regards and Thanks!

https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-forked-8ydvs?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Adding css-property "will-change: transform;" fixes the issue. It's a known issue as discussed here: https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/934